# TimeZone.StandardName showing wrong name on Windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, timezone

```
richTextBox1.AppendText(TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName + "\n");
richTextBox1.AppendText(TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes + "\n");
```

This lines of code has become headache of many of the QAs and developers in our team. It shows **correct** timezone name and UTC offset on Windows 8.1 and 10:

```
Bangladesh Standard Time
360
```

but shows **wrong** standard name the following on Windows 7:

```
Azores Standard Time
360
```

The code is compiled in C# .NET 4.0.

I suspect some PC settings is responsible for this change. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround.

Changing the system timezone to something else fixes this problem. I.e., `TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName` starts to show correct timezone name.

I don't know if it is Windows' bug or .NET's bug.